# Does the mental link between the Jaeger pilots simply just connect and synchronize their movements, or does it also control the Jaeger?

Tags: pacific-rim

In *Pacific Rim*, we see the pilots have a mental link that connects each other, and allows them to share memories, instinct and emotions. Does this mental link sends instructions to the Jaeger too? Because we see the pilots do synchronized moves, but they make physical moves like walking when the Jaeger walks, plus they also pull/push switches and buttons to control the Jaeger.

Are these physical/mechanical moves everything that sends instructions to the Jaeger to pilot it (and the mental link is to synchronize moves with the other pilot) or does this mental link actually sends some fighting/moving instructions to the Jaeger? If so, is there any example of a movement/fighting instruction being sent mentally and not through switches/buttons or physical/mechanical movements like walking or physically move the arms to punch/grab, etc. ?

Comment: Just don't think too hard about the three-armed one.

Comment: We've [already discussed how the three-armed one works](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48487/5184)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The *motor* systems of Jaegers are controlled via neural links to the pilots. Other systems are controlled via buttons and switches.

From the novelization:

> “Neural handshake strong and holding,” he said, as the graphic of two brains converged into one. The links from the overlapped brain image to Gipsy Danger’s control and motor systems lit up.
>
> Raleigh and Yancy were part of it now, and part of each other.
>
> “Right hemisphere ready,” Yancy said.
>
> Raleigh always let him go first, but the tradeoff was that he got to give the all-clear.
>
> “Left hemisphere linked and ready,” he said. “Gipsy Danger ready to deploy.”
>
> They each raised one arm, and Gipsy Danger did the same, confirming the hundred-percent link between the gargantuan Jaeger and the twinned human minds controlling it.

As you mention, there are a number of switches within the control pod. They appear to be used for adjustments to systems, or deployment of weapons. For example, activation of the escape pod, triggering a self-destruct system, or deployment of weapons encased within the Jaeger.

> “You would have seen it if you’d looked,” she answered. She hit a switch on the motion rig’s command console and a glowing sword appeared.
>
> [...]
>
> From Gipsy Danger’s right gauntlet, a long whip made of serrated metal segments woven together with a high-tension cable spilled out into the stratosphere.

Once deployed, the neural link to the Jaeger simulates the physical changes within the minds of the pilots.

> Tendo never got to finish his question. Mako pivoted on the command platform, and their perfect Drift drew Raleigh into the motion as well. He could feel the weight of the sword in his hand, balanced and deadly.

Comment: So the answer to the question in title is "Both"?

Answer (score 8):

The Jaeger's brain capacity is too large for a single human to control, therefore they need two. I don't recall it's ever specified how the division of labor occurs (who does what), but it would even make more sense that neither operator *knows* which part they are controlling.

For the example's sake, let's assume the left operator (A) controls the left side of the Jaeger, and the right operator (B) controls the right side.

If they want the Jaeger to start walking forwards, it needs to put one leg in front of the other. But if A wants to start by putting the left leg forwards, and B wants to start by putting the right leg forwards, then the Jaeger's movement will be erratic and the Jaeger will fall down.

The operators need to be in agreement about the Jaeger's moves, or otherwise they will send mixed signals.

A simple(r) solution would be to have A only move his left limbs, and have B move his right limbs. However, this means that both operators are doing their own thing, and are not able to consider whether their actions conflict with the other's actions.
If operator A (as a human) is incapable of walking by moving both legs forward at the same time, he will notice that when he tries to perform this maneuver. And therefore, he won't accidentally make the Jaeger do something that he can't do himself.

So instead the operators mimic eachother's moves. Even though A's right limbs do not control anything, he still moves them. Because he is now mimicking the *whole* Jaeger instead of only his part, he is always able to consider whether his own actions work together with the actions of their colleague.

There are two possibilities:

- A's movement with his right limbs is free. He can do what he want, because he's not controlling anything with it anyway. This means that he *chooses* to move his right limbs the same way that B does.
- A's movement with his right limbs is not free. The Jaeger forces him to make the same movements as B, because B is controlling the right limbs.

It's been a while since I watched the movie, but I seem to remember a scene where the operators went out of sync and messed up (not the protagonist and his brother). This means that the operators have enough freedom to *choose* to not mimic the other; because otherwise this scene could not have occurred.

This is why operators need to have a close mental connection in order to work together seamlessly. Although it would be possible to have two foreign operators verbally discuss how they are going to walk before attempting to do so; there is no time for discussion when you're in the middle of combat and one of them needs to make a snap decision (e.g. dodging).
Jaeger pilots are therefore expected to know what the other is thinking, so that they can work together well even if under considerable time pressure. They understand one another, and therefore don't waste time disagreeing or trying to think of soemthing together.

So to answer your question: It seems to me that Jaeger pilots *could* move freely and are not being moved around by the Jaeger; but they *should* perform the same movement anyway, to prevent them going out of sync or making separate decisions that conflict.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while but I remember the main Jaeger has a laser type weapon and all the pilot does is position its arm and think (even unconsciously) about firing the weapon. We can see this when the female character is dreaming and arms the weapon only using a defense posture.

Comment: Please construct a stronger case if you wish to answer, preferably with citations.